# Looping over dictionary while using different values to insert and remove keys

Tags: haskell, dictionary, recursion, fold

I'm using vertices and a `Data.Map.Strict`, where I need to implement a capture move for the game Checkers. `cMove` is supposed to take a vertex `k` and a list of vertices `ks` and a map `myMap`. `cMove` needs to check if the new vertex (the position which `k` will get when it jumps over a vertex in `ks`) is in `myMap`, as `myMap` contains the positions of all the pieces on the board. `k` and `k1` (a vertex in `ks`) should be removed from `myMap` and the new vertex should be inserted into `myMap`, where the new vertex should be used to check the next vertex in `ks` and so on, till there are no more elements in the list. I have tried this:

```
type Key = (Integer, Integer)

cMove :: Key -> [Key] -> Map Key Bool -> Map Key Bool
cMove k ks myMap = foldr cMoves' myMap ks
    where
        cMoves' :: Key -> Map Key Bool -> Map Key Bool
        cMoves' k1 myMap = case M.lookup k' myMap of
            Nothing -> M.insert k' False (M.delete k myMap)
            Just x -> myMap
          where
            k' = (2 * fst k1 - fst k, 2 * snd k1 - snd k)
```

which iterates through the list `k1` as supposed and inserts the new vertex. The problem here is, that `k1` is not getting removed and the new vertex is not used instead of `k`. How do I achieve this?

If any part of my question seems vague, don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: It might just be a typo in your question, but you appear to be confusing `k1` (a tuple argument to `cMove'`) and `ks` (the list argument to `cMove`). Also, are `s` and `myMap` supposed to be the same value?

Comment: It was a typo, thank you for noticing. Yes, s and myMap are supposed to be the same value. I have edited the question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: You are also calling `M.delete k`, not `M.delete k1`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to delete both k and k1 from myMap. Is there a way to delete both of them in the same iteration?

Comment: @DanielJørgensen: unless I'm misunderstanding, isn't that simply `M.insert k' False . M.delete k . M.delete k1 $ myMap`?

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I did not know that. Is there a way to apply foldr to `k'` instead of using `k` for the rest of the `ks`?

Comment: @DanielJørgensen Should `k'` *always* replace `k` for the next call, or only when it is/isn't found?

Comment: @chepner `k'` should only replace `k` when it isn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question right, you want to change `k` to `k'` from iteration to iteration. You can do that by changing the state of your fold to include `k` as well:

```
cMove :: Key -> [Key] -> Map Key Bool -> Map Key Bool
cMove k ks myMap = snd $ foldr cMoves' (k, myMap) ks
    where
        cMoves' :: Key -> (Key, Map Key Bool) -> (Key, Map Key Bool)
        cMoves' k1 (k, myMap) = case M.lookup k' myMap of
            Nothing -> (k1, M.insert k' False . M.delete k . M.delete k1 $ myMap)
            Just x -> (k, myMap)
          where
            k' = (2 * fst k1 - fst k, 2 * snd k1 - snd k)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `cMoves'` should return `k1` for the next step instead of `k'`? And is there a way to avoid inserting the vertices with negative values? Like, not inserting (-1,2) and (-2,-4)

Comment: No, I am not sure at all because I don't actually understand the particular problem you're trying to solve :) My answer was aimed at explaining how to change the `k` while you're traversing `ks` and keep modifying `myMap`.

Comment: I see. I found the problem though. foldr takes the last item of the list and traverses from last to first, but I need to do the opposite.